# Add an Image in using Google Maps API v2 in Android

Tags: android, google-maps

[image]How can I set an Image at the certain location in the Google Maps using Google Maps API and handle its click listener? Please provide the step by step solution? Note: I am not talking about Markers.

Comment: What is a "place image"?

Comment: I have Edited the question. Please read again.

Comment: What do you think an "image" is that is not a marker?

Comment: I think you are not getting my point. Lets take an example go to Google Maps on website. Search White House. then you will see the location of the White house pointed with marker. But there is also a small image attached to that location showing the actual View of white house. I want to show That picture. Hope you get it now?

Comment: "But there is also a small image attached to that location showing the actual View of white house" -- no, there is not. There is a marker, labeled A, pointing to the White House. Tapping that marker brings up an info window containing, among other things, a fairly lousy picture of the White House (wonder why Google chose that one...).

Comment: I have attached the image with the question. Kindly look at this. I want to attach images like this programatically in android

Comment: FWIW, I have never seen that behavior in Google Maps.

Comment: I believe the OP is referring to what happens if the "Photos" layer is turned on on the desktop version of Google Maps. (I would suggest that the easiest way to replicate this behavior in Android would still actually be to use the `Marker` API and set a custom image. I'll post a snippet as an answer.)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the easiest way to implement this would be to still use a marker, but set a custom icon.

Something like this should work:
`photoMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(photoLatLng).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.photo)));`

See documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker).